# setAngularVelocity rotates really slowly

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

I am using the basic libgdx box2d to manage physics operations of a game. Everything is working properly, except the rotations: even when I set

```
anyobject.body.setAngularVelocity(someLargeConstant);
```

the object rotates really slowly(and almost at the same speed) no matter what the 'someLargeConstant' is. Except when I use small numbers for parameter, it can rotate slower. Thus I think I somehow have a maximum angular velocity constant inside my world object, which should be set to some small value.

(I also had a similar issue with linear velocity before and I solved it by adjusting the pixels/meter scale. So its unlikely that the problem is a scaling issue.)

How can I enable the objects to rotate faster?

Here is the code I use:

```
private static World world = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);   //Create a world with no gravity
```

to create an object I call another class

```
 public Object(World world, short category, short mask, float x, float y, float radius, Sprite image, 
        float maxSpeed, float frictionStrength, float linearDamping, float angularDamping, boolean movable,
        float elasticity, float mass){

    this.world = world; 
    this.category = category;
    this.mask = mask;
    // We set our body type
    this.bodyDef = new BodyDef();
    if(movable==true){bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;}else{bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;}
    // Set body's starting position in the world
    bodyDef.position.set(x, y);
    bodyDef.linearDamping = linearDamping;
    bodyDef.angularDamping = angularDamping;
    // Create our body in the world using our body definition
    this.body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
    // Create a circle shape and set its radius
    CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
    circle.setRadius(radius);
    // Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
    fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
    fixtureDef.shape = circle;
    fixtureDef.density = (float) (mass/(Math.PI*radius*radius)); 
    fixtureDef.friction = frictionStrength;
    fixtureDef.restitution = elasticity;
    fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = category;
    fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = mask;
    // Create our fixture and attach it to the body
    this.fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
    // BodyDef and FixtureDef don't need disposing, but shapes do.
    circle.dispose();

    ... unrelated functions after that
    }
```

and here I just try to make it rotate fast:

```
    tempBall.body.setAngularVelocity(20000);
```

Comment: We can't see what might be causing the problem if you don't post the code. The problem is not in the method itself so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: I just added everything related

Comment: Try hard-coding your linearDamping and angularDamping to 0. So bodyDef.linearDamping = 0; bodyDef.angularDamping = 0; and see what happens.

Comment: No unfortunately that did not help

Comment: Make sure the value of movable is _true_ . Try to change the values in your FixureDef and see what happens.

Comment: I played with the quantities a lot before but they seem to be irrelevant with this maximum angular velocity. Movable is always true, otherwise I would have problems with linear movement in the first place

Comment: My guess is you are interpreting radians as degrees when you render. Box2D imposes an upper limit on angular velocity of 0.5 radians (90 degrees) per time step. At 60fps this would be 30 radians per second which is extremely fast, but if you use this as degrees, then it's 30 degrees per second which is not that fast. Approximately what speed are you seeing the object rotate at?

Comment: Actually it sounds quite logical, is there a way to convert one to other? It takes about 4 seconds per rotation, so it should be about 90 degrees per second. I use 30fps (more precisely I update with world.step(1/30f, 8, 3);).

Comment: It seems like it is independent of the time step (and velocity&position iterations). More precisely it takes 3.86 (+- 0.03) seconds to complete a full revolution. So probably the reason is something different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem, and it was pretty simple. Im just going to post this here for future googlers:

Object was actually rotating properly, the problem was in my drawing method, I didn't use conversion between radians to degrees in my batch.draw, and it interpreted everything in radians. I know, such an amateur mistake! Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

`angularvilocity` is used to set the direction of the rotation when it comes to use it with an `actionListener` as like key or mouse lister , here is an example of use :

```
 case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
              ball.setAngularVelocity(-20); // Directly set the angular velocity

case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
              ball.setAngularVelocity(20); // Directly set the angular velocity
```

like you can see here the code make the ball body rotate to the right in Key_Right pressed and to the left in Key_Left pressed , and i can play aroud with it's argument to increase or lower the rotation speed and it works pretty well for me , here is my `body` definition try to apply the same values and it must work with no problem :

```
private Body createObject(Shape shape, BodyType type, Vec2 position, float orientation, Sprite sprite) throws InvalidSpriteNameException {
           for(Sprite s:spriteList) {
            if(s.getName().equals(sprite.getName())) {
                throw new InvalidSpriteNameException(sprite.getName()+" already used.");
            }
           }
        Body body = null;
        FixtureDef fixDef = new FixtureDef();
        fixDef.shape = shape;
        fixDef.density = 0.1f;
        fixDef.isSensor = false;
        fixDef.restitution = 0.1f;

        BodyDef bodyDef = new BodyDef();
        bodyDef.type = type;

        bodyDef.angularDamping = 0.1f;
        bodyDef.linearDamping = 0.1f;

        bodyDef.fixedRotation = false;
        bodyDef.gravityScale = 1f;

        bodyDef.linearVelocity = new Vec2(0,0);
        bodyDef.angularVelocity = 0;
        bodyDef.position = new Vec2(position);
        bodyDef.angle = orientation;
        bodyDef.allowSleep = true;
        spriteList.add(sprite); // Save the sprite to the list (sprites must be serialiazed in the PhysicalWorld)
        bodyDef.userData = sprite; // Link the body and the sprite

        do {
            body = jBox2DWorld.createBody(bodyDef);
        } while(body== null); // Wait until the object is really created
        sprite.linkToBody(body); // Link the body to the sprite (this link is not serialiazed)
        body.createFixture(fixDef);
        return body;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I will go through the code, I'm sure that will be enough to locate the source of the problem.

Comment: Honestly I used the exact same code and it made no difference. This is pretty straightforward, could the cause be the way I initialize the world or something like that?