# Box2d setAngularVelocity do not work for high speeds

Tags: java, eclipse, libgdx, box2d, bulletphysics

I am using Box2d for a game, and although I use large constants to set angular velocity, the fastest speed I can get is 1 revolution at 3.86 seconds.

I had checked my source code in the following thread and everything is the same with what I have been suggested from both users in here and in tutorials:

[setAngularVelocity rotates really slowly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28546441/setangularvelocity-rotates-really-slowly)

However than I noticed the following unresolved thread:
http://www.reddit.com/r/libgdx/comments/1qr2m3/the_strangest_libgdxbox2d_behaviour/

and noticed that might actually be the problem. Here is my dispose method

```
    public void dispose() {
    //Get Rid of Everything!
    Assets.Clear();
    GameEngine.Clear();
    BallMap.clear();
    PlayerMap.clear();
    shapeRenderer.dispose();
    debugRenderer.dispose();
    world.dispose();
    batch.dispose();
    font.dispose();
}
```

They are all reinitialized on the beginning as follows:

```
    this.game       = game;
    this.cameraWidth = cameraWidth*pixelRatio;
    this.cameraHeight = cameraHeight*pixelRatio;

    batch           = new SpriteBatch();
    shapeRenderer   = new ShapeRenderer();
    stateTime       = 0F;
    Scores          = new Integer[]{0, 0};

    debugRenderer   = new Box2DDebugRenderer();
    world           = new World(new Vector2(0, 0), true);   //Create a world with no gravity
    GameEngine.setContactListener(world);
```

I navigate through screens with the following code:

```
    public void create () {
    scene_menu = new MainMenuScreen(this, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
    setScreen(scene_menu);
}

public void swtogame(){
    scene_menu.dispose();
    scene_game = new MatchScreen(this, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
    setScreen(scene_game);
}

public void swtomenu(){
    scene_game.dispose();
    scene_menu = new MainMenuScreen(this, cameraWidth, cameraHeight);
    setScreen(scene_menu);
}
```

the way i initialize objects:

```
public Object(World world, short category, short mask, float x, float y, float radius, Sprite image, 
    float maxSpeed, float frictionStrength, float linearDamping, float angularDamping, boolean movable,
    float elasticity, float mass){

this.world = world; 
this.category = category;
this.mask = mask;
// We set our body type
this.bodyDef = new BodyDef();
if(movable==true){bodyDef.type = BodyType.DynamicBody;}else{bodyDef.type = BodyType.StaticBody;}
// Set body's starting position in the world
bodyDef.position.set(x, y);
bodyDef.linearDamping = linearDamping;
bodyDef.angularDamping = angularDamping;
// Create our body in the world using our body definition
this.body = world.createBody(bodyDef);
// Create a circle shape and set its radius
CircleShape circle = new CircleShape();
circle.setRadius(radius);
// Create a fixture definition to apply our shape to
fixtureDef = new FixtureDef();
fixtureDef.shape = circle;
fixtureDef.density = (float) (mass/(Math.PI*radius*radius)); 
fixtureDef.friction = frictionStrength;
fixtureDef.restitution = elasticity;
fixtureDef.filter.categoryBits = category;
fixtureDef.filter.maskBits = mask;
// Create our fixture and attach it to the body
this.fixture = body.createFixture(fixtureDef);
// BodyDef and FixtureDef don't need disposing, but shapes do.
circle.dispose();

... unrelated functions after that
}
```

Am I disposing correctly? Is this a bug? Is there any way to get around it and use the setAngularVelocity properly?

Comment: Where is the code you set the rotation with? And what happens when you exceed 1 rev per 3.86 seconds?

Comment: It just does not exceed 1 rev per 3.86 seconds, I use object.body.setAngularVelocity(5000);
or object.body.setAngularVelocity(1000); and it makes no difference. Only when I set it to something smaller like 5, it rotates even slower than 1 rev per 3.86 seconds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the problem, and it was pretty simple. Im just going to post this here for future googlers:

Object was actually rotating properly, the problem was in my drawing method, I didn't use conversion between radians to degrees in my batch.draw, and it interpreted everything in radians. I know such an amateur mistake! Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Because you haven't shown much code, I can I'm **not** 100% sure that I'm right, but I think that you are hitting the built in maximum movement limit of 2.0 units per time step. This means that at a typical framerate of 60Hz a body covering 2 units per timestep is moving at 120 m/s or 432 km/h (270 mph). Unfortunately it seems that there is no direct way to change this limit in Java, because this limit seems to be defined in the native C++ librarys.

But I think that the **real** problem is that you have a wrong scale. Box2D uses MKS (meters, kilograms, and seconds). And you may have used pixels instead of meters. The FAQ of Box2D suggests to use

> objects [that are] between 0.1 - 10 meters

otherwise you can get strange situations.

See http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/gotchas#speedlimit 
and https://code.google.com/p/box2d/wiki/FAQ

Comment: I am already using a pixel to meter conversion, and changing that ratio does not help, which makes sense because my problem is not with linear displacement but rotation. Most of the source code is in the first thread I have posted, and I am using the same code that other people validated to be working on their application. So something else should be interacting with box2d. Due to the second post I have shared, I thought it may be the way I dispose things or something related but Im not sure thats just the only clue I have. I can share any specific part of my code if it would help?